# Storing small lists of FKs in array column and joining

Tags: schema

Is it (1) possible and (2) faster to use an array to store small lists of Fk's then to use a separate table.

I believe you would use an IN clause to do this but I'm not sure if it's possible to use an IN clause with an Array Column.

I realize on the speed side of the questions it has more to do with
how often the array column is updated and how long it will be. In my case it is a small list 1 - 20 that
will be rarely updated.

Or do you handle these cases a totally different way?

Here is the table structure I was working with if a more concrete example is helpful to answer. I am making a
list users. When I get the user_list I would like to get all their data in the user table as well.

```sql
 create table "user"(
    user_id        uuid,
    username       varchar(140)
    ...
);

create table user_list (
    user_list_id uuid ,
    user_list    uuid[],
    list_name varchar(140)
);
```

```
-- option 2:
-- third table for joining instead of the array column user_list in the user_list table
create table user_list_users(
    user_list_id uuid,
    user_id       uuid
)
```

Comment: Option 2 is the correct one according to proper normalization rules.

Comment: That is true @Charlieface but databases don't have to be always perfectly normalized. Although they definitely should be unless you have a good reason not too. I'm interested in knowing what the performance differences would be if there is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

It's not the update performance you need to worry about. Joining the list of IDs to the user table would be very slow. Databases are heavily optimized to join single columns together. If you store them in an array the database engine needs to unpack the arrays and build a temporary list before it can join the tables. This is a very expensive and slow process. Proper normalization has many performance benefits.

Comment: So the data goes from an array to a list? That doesn't seems like it wouldn't be much of an overhead especially for a small array

Comment: Yes but that's for every single row and then it has to sort the entire list so it adds up. Anyways that an implementation detail by the RDMS which are getting better in handling list type data packed in a single column such as XML and JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach (I am using MySQL 8).

`user` and `user_list` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `user_list` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Sample data for user_list:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | list 1 |
|  2 | list 2 |
+----+--------+
```

Add a constraint on user:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD FOREIGN KEY (list_id) REFERENCES user_list (id);
```

Sample user data:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | list_id |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | u1   |       1 |
|  2 | u2   |       1 |
|  3 | u3   |    NULL |
|  4 | u5   |    NULL |
|  5 | u10  |    NULL |
|  6 | u11  |       2 |
|  7 | u15  |       2 |
+----+------+---------+
```

Sample query on user_list, by list name:

```
SELECT list.name AS list_name, user.name AS user_name
FROM user_list AS list, user
WHERE list.name = 'list 2'
AND list.id = user.list_id
ORDER BY list.name, user.name;
```

This query works fine for your requirement:

> When I get the user_list I would like to get all their data in the
> user table as well.

Comment: This won't work for my example case. Changing the table structure by adding the fk list_id into the user table prevents this from not being a 1 to many relationship